# How to set correct pagination href of next page if having arguments in url - django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, pagination

I am working on a django project but I am facing problem in pagination, on search page if multiple argument are passed in url then how I can set them to href of next page, here what I am trying to do is -

```
  {% if is_paginated %}
        <ul class="pagination pull-right">
          {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li><a href="?q={{ query }}&page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
          {% endif %}
          {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == i %}
              <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
            {% else %}
              <li><a href="?q={{ query }}&page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li><a href="?q={{ query }}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
```

but if first page url is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/products/?q=shirt&brand=Adidas
```

and the next page is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/products/?q=shirt&page=2
```

brand is not there !! it is not possible for me to add each arguments to href as I did for query, is there any way to just add &page{{i}} at the end of url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use template tag to achieve this :

```
@register.simple_tag(name='url_replace')
def url_replace(request, field, value):
   print('this is form tag',request,field,value)
   d = request.GET.copy()
   d[field] = value
   return d.urlencode()
```

and in templates:

```
    {% if is_paginated %}
        <ul class="pagination pull-right">
          {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <li><a href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.previous_page_number %}">&laquo;</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
          {% endif %}
          {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == i %}
              <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
            {% else %}
              <li><a href="?{% url_replace request 'page' i %}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <li><a href="?{% url_replace request 'page' page_obj.next_page_number %}">&raquo;</a></li>
          {% else %}
            <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
          {% endif %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
```

This will work fine.